# Select datetime format using SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table in PostgreSQL created by SQLAlchemy just like that:

```
Column('dt_index_tex', DateTime)
```

If I insert a date like '21-01-2014', when querying I get the date in different format:

```
SELECT dt_index_tex from table;
    dt_index_tex        |        
------------------------+
 2014-01-21 00:00:00    |
```

how could i query in **DMY** format ?

I know in PostgreSQL I have the `to_char` function, but I want something to do with SQLAlchemy, so I don't have to change the format all times I query the table.
I guess I have to try a different way of creating the table, but don't know what is missing.

Comment: What is the code you are using in SQLAlchemy to query the date? If you create it using SQLAlchemy and query through SQLAlchemy, SQLAlchemy should handle the formatting for you and return it as a datetime object (not a string).

Comment: you're right dude, so silly, thank you !